# Hold text when using searchDisplaycontroller

Tags: objective-c

I have a question regarding the searchDisplaycontroller
Everytime when I enter a searchText, my resultstableview gets loaded.
everything works just fine.
But for some reason when I get to didselectrowatindexpath
my searchbar gets empty and I return to textDidChange

Can someone tell me how to fix this? how can I prevent the controller to delete the searchtext?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I really need to see your code to figure out what might be going wrong.  Check to see if you are ever calling [[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] setText:XXX] at all.  That is what would modify the text in the

Answer (score 0):

you are probably setting the controller to not active, thus making it to delete the searchfield.